# downloading kingroot

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have tried to download king root to root my device. Have downloaded it but can't install it onto my phone, this has happened with a root tool as well.these have been downloaded from the internet and unknown sources has been to ticked. I used to be able to download stuff like this before now I cant. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Can u please give the exact problem you are facing, so that it would be easy for us to answer?

Comment: Are you receiving an error message when trying to install? If so a screenshot would be great

Comment: Can you be a little less broad. What is happening what you try to install it? Screenshots are also nice too.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a year, so this isn't necessarily for op, but for anyone with the problem. I just had this problem and fixed it.

Even with unknown sources ticked, I was still getting a warning message. I just pressed okay without looking, and the app wouldn't install.

Instead, when you get that warning just press more info, then press install anyway. It's smaller text and a different color--easy to miss.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

- Try reinstalling browser from which you have downloaded it
- Try checking settings of security apps if you have any

BTW I would suggest you not to use Kingroot because there are some evidences that they still information from your phone and I have myself used it on Galaxy S4 so I know that is it full of bugs and it is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Android builds are difficult to root on their own. You need at least a host PC to flash either a custom recovery or a root zip. To do so, Google your phone model and look for a TWRP or CWM. Download the [SuperSU ZIP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/stable-2016-09-01supersu-v2-78-release-t3452703) and send it to your device. Reboot to bootloader and flash the recovery first, then reboot to the recovery and flash the zip. You're done. It's root now.